# Modify COM Port device name at runtime (Windows)

Tags: windows, serial-port

I'm not sure if this is possible but my requirement is this.

On startup, my application swaps COM1 to COMV1, listens to the output interprets the data and passes it through to COM1.

On shutdown, my applications swaps COMV1 back to COM1 so applications can continue to use it as normal.

Thanks for any help,
Richard

Comment: Why change the port name?  If it's opened as non-shared (default), no other applications will be able to open it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help.

[Null-modem emulator (com0com)](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks leppie. I have been using com0com (great software) to listen to the output but I need to be able to redirect the legacy application to use it first at runtime!